# python serial port reading won't work in batch file

Tags: python, pycharm, pyserial

I have written a python script which reads data from serial port.This script is running on a windows machine. On the other side of serial link there is a micro-controller with a camera connected to it. Micro-controller after taking picture saves it on the flash memory and whenever the python script sends request for that picture, it sends all data in form of lines of strings to the serial port then the script parse through this data and read data line by line and save it in a file which then convert it to the binary image file.
Whenever I run this script in Pycharm it always works fine without any missing data but when I created a batch file for this script and run the batch file, some times there is some missing data during reading data from serial port which cause corrupted image file.
format of data that is read from serial port is like this:

```
20044478: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 E0 01 80 02 3F 00 32

20044488: 12 0B 51 04 51 04 00 00 FF DB 00 84 00 10 0B 0C

20044498: 0E 0C 0A 10 0E 0D 0E 12 11 10 13 18 27 1A 18 16

200444A8: 16 18 30 22 24 1D 27 39 32 3C 3B 38 32 37 36 3F

200444B8: 47 5B 4D 3F 43 56 44 36 37 4F 6B 50 56 5E 60 65

200444C8: 66 65 3D 4C 6F 77 6E 62 76 5B 63 65 61 01 11 12

200444D8: 12 18 15 18 2E 1A 1A 2E 61 41 37 41 61 61 61 61

200444E8: 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61
```

part of code that i think related to this problem is this:

```
def wait_On_serial_camera_capture():
global ser
out_file = open('test.txt', 'w+')
line_read = ser.readline()
# # time.sleep(0.1)
if line_read == "":
    print ("Error in image capturing or problem in transferring image file to the PC !")
while line_read != "":
    line_read = ser.readline()
    # # time.sleep(0.1)
    # # print (line_read)
    sys.stdout.write(line_read)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    out_file.write(line_read)
out_file.close()
ser.close()
```

Comment: Do you still lose data if you omit the write to `sys.stdout`?  That can be quite slow, depending on exactly where stdout is going.  A large scrollable window in a GUI application might require megabytes of pixel data to be shifted around every time it scrolls up a line.

Comment: when i commented out printing to output (sys.stdout) as i tested it before i did not see data lost within several time test. but i need to print out this data somehow. what i can not understand is why i never have had problem with Pycharm just now when i am going to release this code and made batch file see this problem

Answer (score -1):

Check your environments.

You see pycharm has its own environment.
There are two modules `serial` and `pyserial`, and they are different and they both can be imported like `import serial`.
PS: In a GNU/Linux environment, in order to access a device, you need root privileges.

Comment: i use pyserial and run the script in windows. the question is: what pycharm environment has, that batch file doesn't have which cause this missing data sometimes?

Comment: This is not an answer but rather a comment, please do not add comments as answers.